TypeScript check for newly added methods ends with error "Property … does not exist on type 'never'."
When checking for existing of recently added method checkVisibility with in TypeScript generates error:
function isElementVisible(element: Element) {
    return ('checkVisibility' in element) ? element.checkVisibility() : element.getClientRects().length > 0;
}

Error: (2339) Property 'getClientRects' does not exist on type 'never'.
I've rewritten it as follows
function isElementVisible(element: Element) {
    return element.checkVisibility ? element.checkVisibility() : element.getClientRects().length > 0;
}

There is no error in this notation and it does roughly the same so I've settled on it.
I understand why it says never, as from TS perspective lib.dom.d.ts defines checkVisibility so it's always there, though in reality in older browsers it's not there.
But I'm still curious, is there a way make first variant with in to work properly?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#lib

This is ms/TS#51059 and you can take one of the alternative approaches mentioned in there, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what am I missing?

@JaredSmith that doesn't apply here, because it either don't see a method or generates error.

@jcalz yes, casting literal to string first makes TS compiler happy, thank you.

You've run into the issue reported at microsoft/TypeScript#51059.
TypeScript 4.9 introduced unlisted property narrowing with the in operator as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#50666. If you check if ("someKey" in someObj) {⋯} else {⋯}, TypeScript will use that check to narrow the type of someObj. So if the check is true then someObj is narrowed to a type containing someKey, and if it is false then it might be narrowed to a type not containing someKey.  This is working as intended.
But the TypeScript typings for the checkVisibility() method of Elements are written so that the method is always present:
interface Element {
    checkVisibility(options?: CheckVisibilityOptions): boolean;
}

It is not considered optional; it is not declared like this:
interface Element {
    checkVisibility?(options?: CheckVisibilityOptions): boolean;
    //             ^ nope
}

So when you check if ("checkVisibility" in element), TypeScript thinks that will always be true. And thus the else clause ends up narrowing element all the way to the impossible never type.  This is unfortunate, since it interacts badly with the sort of feature testing you're doing. Still, they are leaving it like this, since otherwise you'd pretty much need to write element.checkVisibility?.() using optional chaining even after the feature testing (since possibly checkVisibility is present but undefined, unless you've enabled --exactOptionalPropertyTypes which has even more far-reaching effects).
It's unfortunate but behaving as intended.  You'll need to work around it.

The smallest fix is to use a type assertion or the like to disrupt the problematic narrowing:
function isElementVisible(element: Element) {
  return ("checkVisibility" as string in element) ?
    element.checkVisibility() : element.getClientRects().length > 0;
}

Or you could just read the property instead of using an in check, to avoid narrowing:
function isElementVisible(element: Element) {
  return element.checkVisibility ?
    element.checkVisibility() : element.getClientRects().length > 0;
}

Or you could use optional chaining and nullish coalescing to use the form that would work even if checkVisibility were considered optional:
function isElementVisible(element: Element) {
  return element.checkVisibility?.() ?? (element.getClientRects().length > 0);
}

Or you could pursue any of a number of other workarounds.
Playground link to code
